# Invalid bytes32 value

Tags: truffle, error, bytes32

I am trying to learn about solidity so I just watch a tutorial about it, I already copy the same code as the tutorial but there is an error with bytes32.
Here it is:
[image]

That is the deploy code:
[image]

And that is the .sol:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Replace `['Sat', 'Vit']` with:

- `['Sat', 'Vit'].map(x => web3.fromAscii(x))` if you're on Truffle 4.x (web3 0.x)
- `['Sat', 'Vit'].map(x => web3.utils.asciiToHex(x))` if you're on Truffle 5.x (web3 1.x)

Comment: web3.utils.[asciiToHex](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#asciitohex)